# Why is this function crashing my wordpress installation?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm new to wordpress and programming in general. For my first site there is a custom template in which I want to load a javascript library. After registering and enqueueing it in functions.php my site no longer loads properly. I'm sure what it is simple mistake and would really appreciate a little help. For the record, I'm using a child theme of twentytwelve.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
function load_wforms() {  
    if (is_page(45)) {  
        wp_register_script('wforms', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/wforms.js'), false, '2.0');  
        wp_enqueue_script('wforms');  
    }  
}  
add_action('init', 'wforms');  
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: there's an extra parenthesis here: `'/js/wforms.js')`. [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) so you can see php errors.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I'll be sure to keep a better eye out in the future.

Comment: Actually, I *don't* think this question is **too localized**. The issue of not naming the callback function the same as the second `add_action()` parameter is one that many people (and probably all of us here) have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be sure to enable `WP_DEBUG` in your `wp-config.php` file, so that you can see fatal error messages.

In this case, the problem is that you've named your function `load_wforms()`, but you reference the callback `wforms` in your `add_action()` call:

```
function load_wforms() {}
```

...vs...

```
add_action('init', 'wforms');
```

The second parameter, `wforms`, refers to a function named `wforms()` - but your function is named `load_wforms()`. Change your add_action to this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_wforms' );
```

(Side note: you should enqueue scripts at `wp_enqueue_scripts`, rather than `init`.)

### Edit

Also: fix the syntax error as noted by @milo in his comment:

```
wp_register_script('wforms', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/wforms.js'), false, '2.0');
```

You have an extra parenthesis:

```
'/js/wforms.js')
```

...should be:

```
'/js/wforms.js'
```

Comment: Thanks Chip! I'm sorry for bringing you down to my level on this one...I guess we all have to start somewhere.